# Webpack dev server: Hook or mechanism for trigger command once that the server is running

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, webpack-dev-server, functional-testing, cucumberjs

In my development workflow I open 2 terminal windows for running in one my `npm start task`, once that the server is running at the second window I run a cucumberjs's functional test suite and this worked as i expected. But my problem is that in my CI environment I need run this in a single process. I've been trying this:

`npm start | cucumberjs --require test/functional/ --compiler js:babel-register test/functional/`

The problem with this is the task npm start take a while for run and at the same time the cucumber task try to access to **localhost:3000** (the url when the webpack-dev-server runs) but the server isn't ready yet and the tests fail.

**So, How can I deal with this?**

**The project:** https://github.com/gpincheiraa/angularjs-tdd-jest/tree/dev

**package.json**

```
  ...

  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run stubs & webpack-dev-server",
    "dev": "npm start -- --open",
    "stubs": "stubby -w -d stubs/fakeserver.yml -s 5000",
    "tdd": "cross-env NODE_PATH=./src jest --watch --verbose",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_PATH=./src jest --coverage --verbose",
    "test:functional": "cucumberjs --require test/functional/ --compiler js:babel-register test/functional/",
    //I want in the test:functional-ci task run the npm start and once that is serving the project, run npm run test:functional task
    "test:functional-ci": "cross-env NODE_ENV=staging npm run test:functional",
    "test-debug": "cross-env NODE_PATH=./src node --inspect --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest -i",
    "build": "webpack",
    "check-coverage": "npm test | http-server -so -p 9000 coverage/lcov-report"
  },

  ...
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
      'core-js/shim',
      'babel-polyfill',
      'angular',
      './src/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: 'dist',
        filename: 'index.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
        { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'},
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
        { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
        { test: /\.(html)$/, loader: 'html-loader' },
        { test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader:"url?prefix=font/&limit=5000" },
        { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
        { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" }]
    },
    cache: true,
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
        filename: "index.bundle.js",
        contentBase: "./src",
        port: 3000,
        watch: true,
        publicPath: "/",
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: {
            colors: true,
            chunks: false
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can't you add a logic inside the cucumber task which will check if the server is running (and check this repeatedly say for 5 times, once per minute) and only continue if the server is indeed running?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I can't solve my problem directly with some webpack option. On my CI system I run the following:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "sh -c \"npm run stubs & webpack-dev-server\"",
    ...
    "test:functional": "cucumberjs --require test/functional/ --compiler 
    ...
```

**.travis.yml**

```
before_script: npm start & sleep 7
script: npm run test:functional
```

So when i run `npm start & sleep 7`, I'm giving 7 seconds to `npm start` for that the task do their job and then I run the `npm run test:functional` script.

This is my repo: https://github.com/gpincheiraa/angularjs-tdd-jest
and this is the result in the CI travis log: https://travis-ci.org/gpincheiraa/angularjs-tdd-jest/jobs/271532237